# How can I get the chromium version which the Cobalt use

Tags: version, chromium, cobalt

1.Cobalt is from chromium and it will always update the version.
2. So can I get the chromium version which cobalt use ?
such as cobalt release 11 or cobalt 19.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While Cobalt uses certain parts of Chromium, Cobalt is not a fork of Chromium, and thus there is no single "version" of Chromium that Cobalt uses.